# Laravel +Vue, How to get parameter of url in vue

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5

I have passed an id to the url ie. (http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/article/32). Now i want to get that id in vue to fetch the data only of that id but i have no idea to get that id in vue

my vue script is down below

```js
 <script>

        export default{

            data() {
                return{

                    articles : [],
                    article: {
                        id :'',
                        title : '',
                        body : '',
                        date :''
                    },
                    article_id: ''
                };
            },

            created() {
                this.fetchArticles();
            },

            methods: {
                fetchArticles() {
                    var page_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/article/'+ I want the parameter id here;
                    fetch(page_url)
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(res => {

                            this.article = res.data;
                        })

                        .catch(err => console.log(err));
                }

            }
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you are not using vue-router.

You can use window.location property to get current url object.

You can get current id using
 `var id = window.location.href.split('/').pop();`